# How to show content once to users

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am wondering how to do the following.
- I have a Vimeo video on my website, it's an intro video for my website.
- I want the video to show only once to a user, or if that's not possible, every 5th - 10th time they load the page.

How can I do this? I'm a complete novice at JS. Any tips are welcome!

I found this script, how would I manipulate/use it to do this?

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery cookie plugin you found can do this.

This code will get you started. I don't know how you want to load the video, but this will get you started.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var video_cookie = $.cookie('have_seen_video'); // read the cookie
  if (video_cookie == null) {
    // user has not seen the video
    // TODO: show the video

    // save a cookie to indicate this user has seen the video
    $.cookie('have_seen_video', true);
  } else {
    // user has seen video, don't show it again.
  }
});
```